# Recursive Formula method implemented on another method

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have two recursive methods. One of them has a special formula that I must use on the second method. My task is to write a recursive method named reportOnValues that will use each value in
 a list to compute a recursive formula implemented in the method
 specialRecursiveFunction. I am currently having trouble on implementing the formula to my reportValues method. How could I achieve this.

1st method

```
public static void reportOnValues(MyListOfInts m){
    if (m == null) return;
    else 
        return specialRecursiveFunction(m.firstInt) +   reportOnValues(m.restOfTheInts);
}
```

2nd Method

```
public static double specialRecursiveFunction(int x){
    if (x == 1) return 0;
    else if (x%2==1)
        return 1 + specialRecursiveFunction(x-1);
    else
        return 1 + specialRecursiveFunction(x/2);

}
```

Constructed Linked list

```
public class MyListOfInts {

public int firstInt; // contain data
public MyListOfInts restOfTheInts; // points to next node

public MyListOfInts(int f){ // constructor 1
    firstInt=f;
}

public MyListOfInts(int f, MyListOfInts r){ // constructor 2 implements nodes and data
    firstInt=f;
    restOfTheInts=r;
}
```

}

Comment: It's difficult to tell you you're trying to do. Why have you declared `reportOnValues` as `void` but try to return a value from it?

Comment: what problem are you having on implementing the code, i think the given code will work fine other than the one mentioned by lucero

Comment: I am guessing that `reportOnValues` is supposed to return a `double`?  Please clarify this.

Comment: Yes, sorry it is meant to return a double.

Comment: Then, if you change `if (m == null) return;` to `if (m == null) return 0;` does it work?  If not, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Because my method reportValues is void will I have to print my recursion instead of returning a value?

Comment: I dont want to return 0 because if my node head is null there is nothing to return.

Comment: The problem is that my code is not sending the node data to the special recursion formula

Comment: That's strange... Can you provide a MCVE (as described at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) so we can try to run the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes on your code. I think that this is what you looking for

```
    /*
     * I changed the return type to double.
     * And if (x == 1) return; To if (x == 1) return 0;
     */
    public static double specialRecursiveFunction(int x){
        if (x == 1) return 0;
        else if (x%2==1)
            return 1 + specialRecursiveFunction(x-1);
        else
            return 1 + specialRecursiveFunction(x/2);
    }

    public static double reportOnValues(MyListOfInts m){
        if (m == null) return 0;
        else 
            return specialRecursiveFunction(m.firstInt) + reportOnValues(m.restOfTheInts);
    }
```

> MyListOfInts Class

```
    /*
     * I Added restOfTheInts = null; in MyListOfInts Method
     */
    public class MyListOfInts {

        public int firstInt; // contain data
        public MyListOfInts restOfTheInts; // points to next node

        public MyListOfInts(int f){ // constructor 1
            firstInt=f;
            restOfTheInts = null;
        }

        public MyListOfInts(int f, MyListOfInts r){ // constructor 2 implements nodes and data
            firstInt=f;
            restOfTheInts=r;
        }
    }
```

> And This is How I Tested it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyListOfInts list1 = new MyListOfInts(5, new MyListOfInts(13, new MyListOfInts(18, new MyListOfInts(4, new MyListOfInts(36, new MyListOfInts(5))))));
        System.out.println(reportOnValues(list1));

    }
```

I hope That this is What you looking for, if Not I can help through tell you reach your goal.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: If it is, You can approve the answer as the right answer.